# Guava precondition checks, empty List

Tags: java, guava

I would like to know what is the best pattern for precondition checks on a list from which I will need to pick the first item.

In words, I suppose the list should not be `null` and its size should be > 1.

I find Guava's checkPositionIndex not helpful in this respect. On the contrary, I find it counter-intuitive, see the example below which bombs on an empty list because I use checkPositionIndex rather than checkArgument, as outlined *after* the guard which does not trigger.

It seems like checking position 0 is not sufficient to validate the argument even if I .get(0) from it?

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkPositionIndex;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
public class HowShouldIUseCheckPositionIndex {
  private static class ThingAMajig {
    private String description;
    private ThingAMajig(String description) {
      this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return description;
    }
  }
  private static void goByFirstItemOfTheseAMajigs(List<ThingAMajig> things) {
    checkNotNull(things);
    // Check whether getting the first item is fine
    checkPositionIndex(0, things.size()); // Looks intuitive but...
    System.out.println(things.get(0)); // Finally, help the economy!
    checkArgument(things.size() > 0); // This would have worked :(
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ThingAMajig> fullList =
        Lists.newArrayList(new ThingAMajig(
            "that thingy for the furnace I have been holding off buying"));
    List<ThingAMajig> emptyList = Lists.newLinkedList();
    goByFirstItemOfTheseAMajigs(fullList);
    // goByFirstItemOfTheseAMajigs(emptyList); // This *bombs*
  }
}
```

Comment: `checkArgument(!things.isEmpty())`?

Comment: Yes, sure. Or `.size() > 0` as I type above. But.. don't you agree that `checkPositionIndex` does not really work when the index is 0 and the list is empty? Shouldn't it? I am asking the validator: can I go pick an element from position 0? And it tells me "go ahead"... but I can't, really. This means I need to be careful about the base case... is this not a case of `never make the client do anything the library can do for the client`?

Comment: From the javadoc it seems to throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if index is greater than size - this is not your case, as both index and size are 0. I agree this is not probably what expected, but in the documentation it's stated... however, always use `isEmpty` instead of `size() > 0`, as you may not be aware of how size is computed and it could be a more costly operation instead of just calling `isEmpty()`

Comment: `.isEmpty()` is cleaner, reads better and it's probably always O(c). I agree :) The JavaDoc reads `Ensures that index specifies a valid position...`. Now when the list .isEmpty() that index is actually invalid, at least from the point of view of `get()`ing from it?

Comment: Yes. However the answer axtavt gave makes sense - it's better to use `checkElementIndex()`!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `checkElementIndex()` instead.

`checkPositionIndex()` ensures that the given position is a valid position to insert new element to (i.e. you can do `add(0, obj)` on empty list), not a valid index to get an element from.

Comment: Good point. I was a little bit mislead by the method name. But **I should have read the JavaDoc better**.

Comment: The answer helped me to understand difference between checkElementIndex and checkPositionIndex. It is not obvious which method to use for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do the check at all, in point of fact.

The `list.get(0)` call *itself* will already throw basically exactly the same error message.

But if you *did* want to do the check explicitly, yes, use `checkElementIndex` or `checkArgument(!list.isEmpty())`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [checkElementIndex](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkElementIndex%28int,%20int%29)

It states:

`Ensures that index specifies a valid element in an array, list or string of size size. An element index may range from zero, inclusive, to size, exclusive`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [twitter-commons](https://github.com/twitter/commons) implementation of the [checkNotBlank](https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/base/MorePreconditions.java) method. it validates that an Iterable is not null and not empty. here is the implementation:

```
/**
* Checks that an Iterable is both non-null and non-empty. This method does not check individual
* elements in the Iterable, it just checks that the Iterable has at least one element.
*
* @param argument the argument to validate
* @param message the message template for validation exception messages where %s serves as the
* sole argument placeholder
* @param args any arguments needed by the message template
* @return the argument if it is valid
* @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument has no iterable elements
*/
public static <S, T extends Iterable<S>> T checkNotBlank(T argument, String message,
      Object... args) {
  Preconditions.checkNotNull(argument, message, args);
  Preconditions.checkArgument(!Iterables.isEmpty(argument), message, args);
  return argument;
}
```

Very simple and works on all iterables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use valid4j with hamcrest-matchers instead (found on Maven Central as org.valid4j:valid4j)

For preconditions and postconditions (basically assertions -> throwing AssertionError):

```
import static org.valid4j.Assertive.*;

require(list, hasSize(greaterThan(0)));
```

Or for input validation (throwing your custom recoverable exception):

```
import static org.valid4j.Validation.*;

validate(list, hasSize(greaterThan(0)), otherwiseThrowing(EmptyListException.class));
```

Links:

- http://www.valid4j.org/
- https://github.com/helsing/valid4j